# Customize OSB Mail alert body content

Tags: oracle, osb

I am using Mail as alert-destination in OSB. From proxy service I am calling the alert destination and mail is being sent successfully.

However, the mail content is showing the details of service, destination, timestamp, server name etc details.

I just want to have the payload information in the mail body.

Is therey any way to customize the mail body when adding alert action in a proxy service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you're familiar with creating an alert action. What value did you put in the `expression`?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I put $body and that comes under Payload section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Alert action is very basic, and the email destination isn't really designed to be consumed by humans directly.

You're probably better off alerting to a JMS destination, then dequeuing it using a proxy to transform it into exactly what you want, then route to an SMTP Messaging business service to deliver the email (presumably formatted in HTML).